# While loop Iteration in Sightly/HTL

Tags: while-loop, iteration, aem, do-while, sightly

I have a fair bit of idea of how `data-sly-list` used for iteration in Sightly/HTL.
I have a scenario, where a piece of code has to be iterated based on a variable value that's not a collection. Like a `while` loop.

```
<div class="class1" data-sly-list.item="${variableList}">
        /** pseudo code **/
</div>

**My scenario:**

<div class="class1" "${condition is true -> iterate}" >
        /** pseudo code **/
</div>
```

My Reference: http://www.wemblog.com/2016/02/how-to-sightly-in-aem-cq.html

Comment: Not sure I understand your use case totally, Sightly is meant for presentation layer only, I think you should do whatever you have to do with your variable in the controller (WCMUsePojo Class or JS controller) and use Sightly to display that list of things....

Comment: In the other hand, you can use `data-sly-list` and have a `data-sly-test` inside that displays data only when the condition is met....hope this helps, there is no `while` concept in Sightly, since it's for the presentation layer I don't see a use case to use it....unless my imagination is not that great.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand this can be handled by taking help from backend and data-sly-list. Just curious to know if this can be handled without the help from the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things:
1. Do you want to test the condition once and if meets, show the list?
Solution: Write a data-sly-test and inside that write data-sly-list.
2. You want to test the condition for each of the item in the list?
Solution: Handle it in backend and send the allowed list only. I dont thinks its possible in sightly.

Comment: I understand this can be handled by taking help from backend and data-sly-list. Just curious to know if this can be handled without the help from the backend .

Comment: Thanks for the help.